# Finger control in BlenRig has been deleted! Ups!

Tags: animation, rigging

I just downloaded the character "Vincent" from the Blender Cloud and BlenRig. I have accidentally deleted the finger controller (The stroke that opens and closes the finger). I tried to undo everything with "cmd, Z" (on the Mac) but the controller is still gone. Would be cool if you could help;)

Eyal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it on my own. i just clicked on "Alt H" to unhide the controllers